# Throughput dropped when using two ethernet ports simultaneosly

Tags: linux, gigabit-ethernet

I have a board based on Altera Cyclone V, its ARM SoC is clocked at 800MHz, the boardd has two 1Gbit/s ethernet ports. When I benchmarked the throughput of a single port using iPerf, I managed to get 750Mbit/s. Later on I configure them to be 192.168.128.x and 192.168.129.x and connect them to my dual ports host, then I ran two iPerf instances simultaneously, but this time I only managed to get 600 Mbit/s from each of the port.

I have configured the TX/RX buffers to 4096 and redirect the interrupt of eth0 to core0 and eth1 to core1. Any idea to further increase the throughput? My target is to get at least 750Mbit/s per port.

Comment: I don't know the specs of the board you are using, but it's possible that whatever connection is being used from the network components to the processor has a maximum throughput that is around 1200 Mbit/s. A place we used to see this type of limit a lot was with Dual-port Gigabit NICs in 32-bit PCI slots - the 32-bit PCI bus couldn't handle data fast enough to saturate both network ports. (Although the NICs were primarily designed for a 64-bit PCI slot, they still fit in the smaller 32-bit slot with some of the pins hanging out the back unconnected.)